# ImportError: No module named pycurl - developing an OpenStack Horizon Plugin

Tags: python, python-2.7, openstack, openstack-horizon

I'm developing an openstack horizon plugin that should poll some info via a ReST API. I'm following this tutorial:  http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/topics/tutorial.html

So in the file /opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/mydashboard/mypanel/views.py I have:

```
from horizon import tabs
from horizon import views

from openstack_dashboard.dashboards.mydashboard.mypanel import tabs as mydashboard_tabs

import sys
import pycurl
```

Resulting in `ImportError: No module named pycurl`

If I load python and check, pycurl is loadable:

```
oink@ubuntu14-devstack:/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/mydashboard/templates/mydashboard/mypanel$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pycurl
>>> pycurl
<module 'pycurl' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycurl.so'>
```

OpenStack is running python version `2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) [GCC 4.8.2]`, which matches my line interpreter. How would I be able to use pycurl in an OpenStack Horizon view? (Or, what is a good mechanism to poll a ReST API from Horizon?)

Comment: try import pycurl.so. Just a try though :-)

Comment: Nope, `ImportError: No module named pycurl.so`.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualenv is in the way?

Meanwhile I'm using this hack:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages")
import pycurl
```